# ASP.NET CheckBoxList display multiple lines

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

with ASP.NET CheckBoxList, I need display multiple lines

Ex:

Line1: 5 checkbox

Line2: 6 checkbox

Line3: 2 checkbox

I'm using RepeatDirection="Horizontal" and RepeatColumns ="5"
but cannot display 6 checkbox.
How to display it?

Comment: you mean for the same checkboxlist or one per line?

Comment: I have a checkboxlist. With 13 items (13 checkbox)

With RepeatDirection and RepeatColumns I'm only display:
Line 1: 5 items

Line  2: 5 items

Line 3: 3 items.
But I want: Line 1: Displays 5 items

Line 2: Displays 6 items

Line 3: Display 2 items

Comment: In ASP.Net we have little control on the Html rendered by server side controls unless render method is overridden. See https://forums.asp.net/t/1307821.aspx?overriding+the+CheckBoxList+render+method Create your own check box list based on the one provided by ASP.Net

Comment: @FixBug it would be easy if you use javascript for this one. Then throw your data from your frontend to your backend.

Comment: The easiest way is to just create 3 CheckBoxLists and merge the results in code behind.